# Uncaught TypeError: Custom element constructor returned a wrong element

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I try to learn WebComponents, and it's not easy as that technology is unclear yet and a bit underdeveloped.
The main issue I have with it, it's based on JavaScript Class syntax, where I try to keep code in a functional/prototype programming way.

Then made this script. Custom Element exists, inherits HTMLElement methods, shadowDom, and also styling does work.

But...

I encountered error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <x-foo></x-foo>
        <script>
            function Xfoo( str ) {
                this.str = str;
            };

            let XFoo = "x-foo";
            XFoo.constructor = "x-foo";

            HTMLElement.prototype.XFoo = new Xfoo();

            customElements.define( XFoo, XFoo.constructor );

            const xfoo = document.getElementsByTagName(XFoo)[0];
            console.log( xfoo );
            const shadow = xfoo.attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );

            const styleNode = document.createElement("style");
            styleNode.textContent = `
                * {
                    background-color: blue;
                    font-size: 32px;
                }
           `;

            shadow.appendChild( styleNode );

            const text = document.createElement("span");
            text.textContent = "content";
            shadow.appendChild( text );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Custom element constructor returned a wrong element
    <anonymous>
```

I tried to look through documentation, but can't find what that constructor element should return, so I can just return it... Or figure out the way to make it properly.

EDIT: Summary - This Script Works. I just want to get rid of this error. Get to know how to fix it or make it better, avoiding OOP and Class based code as much as I can.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Custom Elements API is class based inheritance.

You are using a lot of *oldskool* JavaScript.
You probably looked at very old blogs, referencing the old V0 version of Web Components.
Which mainly was a Google party only, never a standard.

It is better to **discard** any blogs or StackOverflow posts over 4 years old,
just to be sure you are looking at **V1** **standard** Web Components information, created by Apple+Mozilla+Microsoft+Google.
MDN and Mozilla documentation are 99,9% accurate.

You code should be **something like** this:

```js
customElements.define("x-foo", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
           .innerHTML = `<style>
           :host{
            background-color: blue;
            color:gold;
            font-size:32px;
            }
           </style>
           Hello Web Component!
           `
  }
})
```

```html
<x-foo></x-foo>
```

Comment: No. My recent documentation comes from January 2022. I went through many blogs and examples from MDN, to Medium, also other sources that were between 2019-2021. 
Yes. I know it's Class based. 
But I hate Class based JavaScript where JavaScript is Functional / Prototype Programming language. I want to avoid OOP as much as I can, and I know there is a solution for my answer. 
My code is based on newest articles. If I would make this code from some 4 year old article it wouldn't work from what I've seen.

Comment: The problem is I don't know JavaScript in browser specification that well, to get into the bottom of this error. 
I tried to get through documentation of `customElement.define()`, but didn't know what to look for.

Comment: Good luck, I have learned not to fight the OOP beast, became a lot more productive. I hate React, though. You always have to hate at least one thing in the JS world :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially [impossible](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/587#issuecomment-253993830) to write web components without ES6 classes. If you do find a solution that works you'll never be able to search for documentation or guides and if you run into issues there won't be Stack Overflow posts about how to fix them.

> It's not possible to use custom elements without ES6 classes. That was a design decision necessary to achieve consensus at the January face-to-face meeting.

It looks like it might be [possible](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/587#issuecomment-378684197), but the implementation is very convoluted.

```js
function MyEl() {
  return Reflect.construct(HTMLElement,[], this.constructor);
}

MyEl.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
MyEl.prototype.constructor = MyEl;
Object.setPrototypeOf(MyEl, HTMLElement);

MyEl.prototype.connectedCallback = function() {
  console.log('my-el connected');
};
customElements.define('my-el', MyEl);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('my-el'));
```

If you are really set on not writing classes, I'd recommend you check out [haunted](https://github.com/matthewp/haunted). It's got a nice pattern for writing components without writing classes.

```js
function Counter() {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

      return html`
        <div id="count">${count}</div>
        <button type="button" @click=${() => setCount(count + 1)}>
          Increment
        </button>
      `;
    }

    customElements.define('my-counter', component(Counter));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the [solution](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/587#issuecomment-254017839) yesterday on the same [Issue](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/587) as @[abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26406/abraham) in his answer.

```js
function CustomElement() {
    return Reflect.construct(HTMLElement, [], CustomElement);
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(CustomElement.prototype, HTMLElement.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(CustomElement, HTMLElement);

customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
```

It seems to be possible, and I need to look through all that topic + MDN documentation to get how does all of their solution works.